# Unhandled promise rejection Bookshelf.js

Tags: node.js, promise, bookshelf.js

I am trying to set up password reset scheme with bookshelf.js ORM, but I am stuck with unhandled promise rejection error

```
var verifyEmail = function(useremail) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            User.where('email', useremail)
            .fetch()
            .then(user => {
                if (user === null) {
                    reject(new error.ERROR_404());
                }
                resolve(user.toJSON());
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(new error.ERROR_500(err));
            })
        })
    }

    var recoverPassword = function(req, res) {
        var useremail = req.body.email;

        //verify email exists
        verifyEmail(useremail)
        .then(user => {
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(err.status).json(err);
        })
    }
```

I feel like I am handling promises okay... what would be the issue?

Comment: Glancing at the code, I don't see any potential unhandled rejections. What is the exact error that you're getting? Hopefully it has a stack trace with line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch a user, Bookshelf already returns a Promise so you don't need to create a new Promise separately. And if you want to, you must return Bookshelf Promise something like this

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return User.where('email', useremail)
```

Or you can simply write your function like this

```
var verifyEmail = function(useremail) {
    return User.forge()
        .where('email', useremail)
        .fetch()
        .then(user => {
            if(!user)
                return Promise.reject();
            return user.toJSON();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return Promise.reject(new error.ERROR_500(err));
        })
    })

var recoverPassword = function(req, res) {
    var useremail = req.body.email;

    //verify email exists
    verifyEmail(useremail)
        .then(user => {})
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(err.status).json(err);
        })
}
```